# The item that you were attempting to purchase could not be found

Tags: android, maui, in-app-billing

I have setup in app purchasing on Android and the Google Play Store. When I try to purchase the product from the Android app it returns this error: The item that you were attempting to purchase could not be found.

I have made sure of the following:

You MUST use a physical device. Emulators do not work.

Ensure you have app in Alpha/Beta with the NuGet installed.

Create an IAB product, make sure it is published and active.

Add a test account to the app, ensure it is the main account on device, and that account is opted-in as tester.

Validated your version code and number in your development environment match what is in the Play store.

You MUST sign the APK even in debug mode.

Please could I receive some support. Many Thanks!

Bug Information
Version Number of Plugin: 7.1.0
Device Tested On: Physical Samsung A40
Simulator Tested On: N/A
Version of VS: 17.6.7
Version of Xamarin: .NET Maui 7.0.100

Steps to reproduce the Behavior:
Setup in app billing on Android and Google Play.

Expected Behavior:
Should be able to purchase the product.

Actual Behavior:
Error: The item that you were attempting to purchase could not be found.

Code snippet

```
var purchase = await billing.PurchaseAsync(productId, ItemType.InAppPurchase);
```

Screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem.
I was getting same error message that you are getting.
The test application worked fine on my phone but I was unable to make purchases.
The solution that worked for me was to accept the test invite and opt into the test program.
Just because the app works on your phone does not mean you have accepted the test invite and opted into the test program.

Confirm that you have accepted the test program invitation.

1. Go to your app test release page on play console
2. Select the Testers tab
3. Copy the web link provided
4. Open the link on your phone browser or emulator browser with the test account
5. Accept the invitation to join the test program.
6. Try making the purchase once more.

[image]

You should see this when you open the link on your phone

[image]

Comment: this is the answer, thank you! And Google, shame on you how you ALWAYS manage to make something overly complex & simultaneously omit important details in your (always incomplete) official docs. You gotta jump through so many hoops implementing your IAP - that is not how you should make APIs...